# Apache won't run even though port 80 is available

Tags: apache, server, xampp, port

So I used Apache last time yesterday, opening up Port 80 so that it could access it. Today, without changing any settings, it won't start. I've made Port 80 available, I've tried changing the Listen 80 to Listen 8080 and multiple other ports but it won't work. I've also opened XAMPP in administrator since I've read that it could be privilege problems, but that doesn't seem to be the problem aswell. The error message I receive is:

17:16:51  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...

17:16:51  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

17:16:51  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped

17:16:51  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

17:16:51  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

17:16:51  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

17:16:51  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

17:16:51  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

17:16:51  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this

17:16:51  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

EDIT: Apache doesn't seem to update the error_log file aswell. So I can't find any information there. I guess this is the problem, but I've found nothing to solve it.

Comment: next step for you is to check the Apache's error_log file

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that. The error_log file doesn't update anything from today. So there's nothing from today in that file, just from yesterday. Why is that?

Comment: Makes no difference, I've tried multiple ports and none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume Apache Service is installed and running

press `Windows+R` and run `services.msc`

Find service name Apache and stop it.

In xampp Control panel you will find service with green sign or red x sign

Uninstall Apache service then install it and then try to start Apache on port 80

this should work, else try reinstalling xampp.

Comment: Apache Service was not in services.msc, so I installed it through the green/red sign in XAMPP. But it's not possible to even start it through services, it's automatically stopped. If I try to start it through XAMPP after doing this, it's just "Attempting to start Apache service...", with nothing happening. Does this mean it isn't installed?

Comment: it is possible to start it through services, go back to the services.msc
right click on apache's service and choose Properties if you see Startup type Disabled change it to Manual and try to start it.

Comment: It says (translating from Swedish, might not be 100% accurate): Couldn't start Apache2.4 on Local Computer. More information is in the system log. (Which by the way, does not update from today. Error code: 1

Comment: open C:\xampp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat 
and then open apache_installservice.bat after that try to  start the service

Comment: I reinstalled it as you said from the beginning, and now it works. When I tried to start apache through apache_start, it kept finding errors in the httpd.conf and httpd.xampp.conf files. I don't know why or how, however it is working now thanks to reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error as you cought.

My mistake was putting backward slash in 'DocumentRoot' of my virtual hosts at 'httpd-vhost.conf' file.

When I changed the backslash to forward slash it worked.