# How to use Apache to write php language

Tags: php, apache, server, port

I installed Apache to write php programs. But I have a problem, when I open Apache, it say me that the port 80 is busy.
What can I do?

Comment: are you running any service that uses port 80? What OS are you running?

Comment: I think you might find Skype uses port 80, that's a common reason.  You can change the Apache settings to listen to another port.

Comment: Could you explain me with an answer how can I do? Can I close Skype to use port 80 in Apache? If I can close Skype what is the process to do that?

Comment: Your solutions is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994888/why-skype-using-http-or-https-ports-80-and-443

Comment: I think this might solve your problem. Just check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259352/8069943).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 80 port is used by another server , that's why you can change the port number from apache httpd.conf.

If you use windows  , you can use wamp or xampp server ,
or you use linux , you can use lamp server in order to develop php application.